# How do I access the ListBox of a TComboEdit in FireMonkey?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I can easily access the `ListBox` of a `TComboBox` to change its style properties in the `OnEnter` event, like this:

```cpp
combo_box->ListBox->StylesData["shadow.Softness"] = TValue::From<float>(0.3 * magnify_ratio);
```

Or, to deselect all items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < combo_box->ListBox->Items->Count; i++)
    combo_box->ListBox->ListItems[i]->IsSelected = false;
```

But, how can I do the same for the `ListBox` of a `TComboEdit` in the `OnPopup` event? I got an error:

> [bcc32c Error]: no member named 'ListBox' in 'Fmx::Comboedit::TComboEdit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try type-casting the [`TComboEdit::Presentation`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.Presentation.TPresentedControl.Presentation) property to [`TStyledComboEdit`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ComboEdit.Style.TStyledComboEdit) and then use the [`TStyledComboEdit::ListBox`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ComboEdit.Style.TStyledComboEdit.ListBox) property, eg:

```cpp
#include <FMX.ComboEdit.Style.hpp>

static_cast<TStyledComboEdit*>(combo_box->Presentation)->ListBox->...
```

Comment: Remy, thank you so much, it worked! You also need to #include <FMX.ComboEdit.Style.hpp> for TStyledComboEdit.